# How to run php command line automatically?

Tags: php, laravel, deployment

Now I have a Laravel project, and I want to deploy to the server. My application needs to run some laravel command line just one time to deploy.

Ex: `php artisan key:generate`, or `php artisan storage:link`.

How can I autorun those command-line when deploying the application to the server?

P/s: Of course I can run by typing, but I don't want. Any best solution to run all of them just by one manipulation?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/artisan#scheduling-artisan-commands

Comment: Could try [Envoy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/envoy). "_Of course I can run by typing, but I don't want._" That's two lines you need to type!

Comment: You can use composer post-install scripts.

Comment: @kerbholz I know I can type, but I don't want. I just want to find a solution to run all of them one time.

Comment: @jrswgtr Any example, I'm not good at composer

Comment: @HenryBui see janmyszkier's answer!

Comment: You should only run that command the first time you deploy and not each time you deploy. You should not modify the .env after that unless you actually need to change configuration, which is why it's not recommended to automatically run that command.

Comment: depends what kind of access and environment your server has, you can make server sided scripts, or as the current accepted answer use composer.

Comment: @apokryfos, @killstreet, Thanks for your advice. I did like what @janmyszkier's answer and put the `composer run-script compile` to bash.sh. When I need to deploy to other servers, just run `sh bash.sh`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you're using composer there are commands you can provide in scripts node.
See https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md for more details.
then you can also define your own script. i.e compile:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "compile": [
      "mkdir logs",
      "echo 'hello world'",
      "./deploy/heroku/run.sh"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "echo composer finished installing, do your commands here"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "echo composer finished updating, do your commands here"
    ]
  }
}
```

and run with `composer run-script compile`